# Accessing TeamCity build parameters from a FAKE build script?

Tags: f#, teamcity, f#-fake

In TeamCity you can specify build parameters which can then be accessed by MSBuild. I currently use this feature to distinguish between deployment environment targets using a system parameter called `DeployTo`. I thought this would be accessible through `Fake.EnvironmentHelper` but when I print `environVar "DeployTo"` there is nothing there. I have also tried listing `environVars EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` but it is not listed there either.

I have tried passing it in as a command-line argument like so:

```
build.fsx Deploy --envvar DeployTo Test
```

or

```
build.fsx Deploy -ev DeployTo Test
```

However, instead of passing "Test", the environment variable is set to "true"

Is there any way to access a TeamCity build parameter from a FAKE build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to see parameter as environment variable, you must define it with prefix `env.`.

If you define a parameter `env.DeployTo` with value `Test`, it will be accessible to the build as environmental variable `DeployTo`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to do it is through the command line. I had the wrong syntax, the correct syntax would be:

`build.fsx DeployTo=test`

Comment: That's a build parameter, not a environment variable.